# Login and Stay Logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hey so I have a website which asks the user to input their username and password and then it checks with my MySQL database to see if the credentials are correct. Now if it is, I want it so that the user then has access to other parts of the website but without having them to contently re-enter their information. Basically keep them logged into the website.

I have never done something like this before and I'm trying to go above and beyond the class projects requirements. How would I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions but with different behavior:

**1st:** is to use [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).
The session support allows you to store data between requests in the `$_SESSION` superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated. For example, you can store if a user is logged in with this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['loged_in']="yes";
```

and retrieve the value using this:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loged_in']=="yes"){ echo "logged in!"; }
```

**2nd:** is [PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). PHP transparently supports HTTP cookies. Cookies are a mechanism for storing data in the remote browser and thus tracking or identifying return users. You can set cookies using the setcookie() or setrawcookie() function. Cookies are part of the HTTP header, so setcookie() must be called before any output is sent to the browser. This is the same limitation that header() has. You can use the output buffering functions to delay the script output until you have decided whether or not to set any cookies or send any headers.

Cookies store credentials locally and make it available again whenever user access the same webpage again. It is where you store login details when you checked the *"keep me login"* checkbox. It is different from session in way that cookies can be accessed again even the browser is closed and the computer is shutted down.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cookies. How to here : http://php.net/manual/fr/features.cookies.php

With session variable, you can verifies that user is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it

1. Session
2. Cookie

If you are using Session, then user has to login everytime after he closes his browser. If you use Cookie then it saves a login information locally on users computer (as you must have seen 'Remember Me' on various websites) and user will automatically login. You can use both option simultaneously and give 'remember me' option on user discretion

Now, there are security issues related with Cookie (as you can never see 'remember me' on bank websites etc, you may see it for remembering username).

Also, in this kind of setup, you have to check user credentials on every page that should only be accessible by authorized user.

Write SQL Injection preventive code as its very easy if not coded properly and moreover its not rocket science.

To begin with this kind of setup you can follow some youtube tutorial. There are tons of those. Here is a link for a tutorial http://www.developphp.com/list_php_video.php#How_to_Build_a_Social_Network_Website
This is a good tutorial for beginners. Tutorial 1-9 will solve your purpose. Once you are an expert you can write your own customized and clean code. These tutorial will help you understand the basics of a kind of system you want to design after that its on your learning and perception. Then Sky is the Limit :)